# Use single profile on checkout from cart

Tags: civievent

I'm trying to use the cart checkout to simplify checkouts for parents registering their children in multiple classes over the summer. Many sign up for 8 classes, and when they get to checkout, they have to enter all their information for all 8 classes.
Does anyone have experience altering the checkout to check if the same profile is being used on the multiple events to just use one?

Edit: Alternatively, is there a way to assign a profile to the overall cart checkout, so the profiles used for the individual events could be shortened?

Comment: how did you end up doing this John?

Comment: No solution petednz. I set up a price set with check boxes on the classes that are most commonly signed up in bulk. The only sollution I could find was with Webforms if I migrated everything to Drupal, which I tried testing twice, but wasn't able to get Drupal 8 working, yadayada, and just kept this annoying system.

Comment: I would not be recommending D8 - D7 still has years of life and has all the bits that you require fully working. D8 is still missing Webform integration. but sounds like this is history - we have ended up achieving some very complex event 'checkout' options via Webform - happy to demo if you are still in the mood for exploring this

Answer (score 2):

Just so you know, there's two extensions currently under development for CiviCRM, and specifically that integrate with CiviCRM's Event Cart feature, that might meet some of your needs. They're under active development, and you can check them out on CiviCRM's GitLab.

[boxoffice](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/boxoffice): Provides a lighter workflow for the CiviCRM Event Cart. Designed for a ticket box office (ex: where you do not need the names of other participants).

[eventpack](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/eventpack): Provides a way to bundle events together (at a discounted price) in the CiviCRM Event Cart (and the Boxoffice extension).